# win Server not responding to DHCP Discover on vlans

Tags: windows, dhcp, vlan, windows-server-2019

Im pretty new to the topic, Im an electronics engineer so im naturally missing something in my IT config :-)

im trying to set up a network for a non-profit organisation (small sports club) with the existing hardware:

the ISP modem                                       - 192.168.25.1

a L3 switch/router ProCurve2626                     - 192.168.25.2

A freshly installed windows Server 2019 for DHCP    - 192.168.25.3

Server is set up with 3 scopes:

vlan1 -

192.168.25.50 - 192.168.25.230

router/gateway: 192.168.25.1, DNS:192.168.25.1

vlan10 -

192.168.26.5 - 192.168.26.254

router/gateway: 192.168.26.2, DNS:192.168.25.1

vlan20 -

192.168.27.5 - 192.168.27.254

router/gateway: 192.168.27.2, DNS:192.168.25.1

Switch config:

`hostname "ProCurve Switch 2626"
ip default-gateway 192.168.25.1
ip routing
snmp-server community "public" Unrestricted
vlan 1
   name "management"
   untagged 1-4,13-26
   ip address 192.168.25.2 255.255.255.0
   ip helper-address 192.168.25.3
   no untagged 5-12
   exit
vlan 10
   name "mitglieder"
   untagged 5-8
   ip address 192.168.26.2 255.255.255.0
   ip helper-address 192.168.25.3
   tagged 13-15
   exit
vlan 20
   name "gaeste"
   untagged 9-12
   ip address 192.168.27.2 255.255.255.0
   ip helper-address 192.168.25.3
   tagged 13-15
   exit
gvrp
ip route 192.168.27.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.25.1
ip route 192.168.26.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.25.1`

I get a DHCP adress when im plugged into a port untagged with Vlan1, but not on Vlan10 or Vlan20, does anyone see what im doing wrong/ what's missing?

in wireshark i see a DHCP Discover, source is the switch, destination the DHCP server

any hints would help, best wishes

Jonny

Comment: The Windows server isn't your DHCP Helper (relay) unless you installed the RRAS role and configured it as a DHCP relay, which I'm guessing you didn't. Why not use the switch as your DHCP relay?

Comment: i changed the IP helper address to the switch (vlan10 ...26.2 and vlan20 ...27.2,) now I dont even see the Discover anymore.
What am i doing wrong?
it's my 4th day of struggling with this problem

Comment: I'm certain that you have to enable the DHCP relay service on the switch. You'll need to make sure that the switch is also performing inter-vlan routing.

Comment: Thanks so far! DHCP relay is enabled, how would the routing have to look like?
Do i need to have a route from vlan10 to the DHCP?
-like
ip route 192.198.26.0/24 192.168.25.3

Comment: With a Cisco switch you would simply enable ip routing. I'm assuming it's the same with an HP switch. You shouldn't need to manually create any routes.

Comment: Im going crazy... it still does not work, why can i see the Discover on wireshark on the server but no answer? Is the only possible reason routing options?